# How to load redis modules to redis-server

Tags: node.js, redis

I am in windows and want to load external redis modules such as Redisearch and RediSQL packages in redis-server .
For which i download a .so file and want to load it to redis-server .
What is the best way to do that please send .
I am using windows OS.

Comment: How do you run the server on Windows? notice these modules are only supported on Linux. You can run redis-server in the windows sub system

Comment: Yes i run the redis-server in windows . And download it from the 
https://github.com/microsoftarchive/redis/releases
And works perfectly like redis

Comment: Please notice this is an old unmaintained version of Redis (the latest version of Redis is 6.2), In order to deploy these modules you need a much newer version of Redis.

Answer (score 2):

As Victor pointed out you are using an abandoned Redis project by Microsoft called OpenTech Redis.

I suggest you checkout Memurai.
Memurai is an up-to-date native Windows port of Redis that derives from that project (see [this commit](https://github.com/microsoftarchive/redis/commit/287e01c68ce9ec6e7a739c19b04b1dfc253326e3)).

Memurai is also available with a free Developer Edition.

Disclaimer: I work in Memurai.

Answer (score 0):

[microsoftarchive/redis](https://github.com/microsoftarchive/redis)

> This project is no longer being actively maintained.

> This repository has been archived by the owner. It is now read-only.

The latest version of **Redis for Windows** is `v3.2`.

**Redis Modules** support appeared only in `v4.0`.

---

Alternatively, you can try using [WSL2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/about) to run the latest Redis with module support.